# C# FileInfo Array to String Array

Tags: c#, arrays, fileinfo

I have an array that stores files from a directory:

```
    string pathToDirectory = @"C:\files";
    System.IO.DirectoryInfo diDir = new DirectoryInfo(pathToDirectory);
    System.IO.FileInfo[] File_Array = diDir.GetFiles();

    foreach (FileInfo lfileInfo in File_Array)
    {
    }
```

I want to try and convert this array into a string type array instead of a FileInfo type. Please let me know how I can go about doing this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: And what is in the strings ? The filenames?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use static [`Directory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.aspx) class instead. It returns files as strings instead of instantiating `FileInfo` instances which you don't need

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(pathToDirectory);
```

If you want just file names without path, then use [`Path`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.aspx) to get rid of directory path:

```
var fileNames = Directory.GetFiles(pathToDirectory)
                         .Select(Path.GetFileName);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string[] fileNames = File_Array.Select(f => f.Name).ToArray();
```